# DAX formula for count of rows with multiple filters

Tags: excel, count, powerbi, dax

I have a requirement to find the number/count of products that have more than 3 "Credit Card" billings by month. The table name is "Transactions"

I have the data as pictured below. How can I do this using DAX?

```
Product ID | Billing Type | Year-Month
-----------|--------------|------------
1            Credit Card    2018-01
1            Credit Card    2018-01
1            Online         2018-01
2            Credit Card    2018-01
2            Credit Card    2018-01
1            Credit Card    2018-02
1            Credit Card    2018-02
1            Credit Card    2018-02
1            Credit Card    2018-03
7            Credit Card    2018-03
7            Credit Card    2018-03
4            Credit Card    2018-03
4            Credit Card    2018-03
1            Online         2018-03
1            Online         2018-03
7            Credit Card    2018-04
1            Online         2018-04
5            Online         2018-04
```

[Transactions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGFT0.jpg)

Comment: There are no `Product ID` values in this table that have more than 3 Credit Cart billings in a single month. Did you mean more than 3 total?

Comment: Yes @Alexis Olson. Thanks for your help. That is just a sample table. Count of Distinct Product ID is more than or equal to 3

Comment: So for this particular question, the third column is irrelevant, correct?

Comment: Third column (Year-Month)? If yes, then not exactly irrelevant. Because I need to show the data only for the  months satisfy this condition "distinct count of product id's with "Credit Card" billing type is greater than or equal to 3 by month"

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a table of `ProductID` values along with the number of credit card transactions as follows:

```
CalculatedTable =
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        Transactions[ProductID],
        Transactions[Year-Month],
        "Count",
        COUNTX(FILTER(Transactions, Transactions[BillingType] = "Credit-Card"), 1))
```

(Leave out the `Transactions[Year-Month]` line if you don't want to group by date.)

If you wrap a filter around that, you can generate a table that has only the `ProductID` values that satisfy the filter. Then just count the rows in that table.

```
ProductCount = COUNTROWS(FILTER(CalculatedTable, [Count] >= 3))
```

---

**Edit:** It sounds like I misinterpreted what you were trying to ask. The following will give you a calculated table that matches the SQL query you gave in your comment:

```
CalculatedTable =
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
            Transactions[Year-Month],
            "RowCount",
            CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Transactions[Product ID]), 
                      Transactions[Billing Type] = "Credit Card")),
        [RowCount] >= 10)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error while using 

CalculatedTable =
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        Transactions[ProductID],
        Transactions[Year-Month],
        "Count",
        COUNTX(FILTER(Transactions, Transactions[BillingType] = "Credit-Card"), 1))

Error: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: basically, I need the following SQL script in DAX

    Select * From(Select distinct Count([Product ID]) as [RowCount] ,[Year-Month] from Transactions
 where [Billing Type] = 'Credit Card' 
 GROUP BY [Year-Month]
 ) as Base
Where Base.[RowCount] >= 10'

Comment: @Akhil I'm not positive, but it sounds like you didn't make `CalculatedTable` a table, but rather a measure. If you don't want to create a separate table, then just insert its code into the `ProductCount` measure.

Comment: It is working. Thanks! I have another requirement. Can you help me with the that as well? (separate chat may be)